# What are these worm-like creatures?

Tags: species-identification

I was reading a book in the balcony and I encountered these animals. They look like worms but I don't know if they are worms or insect larva.

I investigated a little and I found a dead pigeon at the balcony of the upper floor which had a lot of these creatures inside its body.

They have a black thing under their skin near the head and they move like drunken people on the ground.

Also, at the mouth they have a tiny black proboscis-like thing (not present in the picture).

Are these worms or insect larva?

[image: worms]

Comment: most likely fly larvae, also known as maggots, don't know which species.